# Double click on jar (netbeans built) and nothing happens. Write java -jar from prompt get null pointer exc

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, nullpointerexception

I'm quite new to java, so i'm sorry if i'm not noticing some mistake i made.
As the title said, when i build a project which is perfectly running on Netbeans 7.2.1 and then double click on the jar file, nothing happens.
Checking on the web i read it was suggested, in order to spot errors better, to go to the command prompt and write:

```
java -jar C:\Users\conserva\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EasyText\dist\EasyText.jar
```

It'gives me this:

```
C:\>java -jar C:\Users\conserva\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EasyText\dist\EasyText.jar
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at easytext.MainWindow.<init>(MainWindow.java:25)
        at easytext.MainWindow$4.run(MainWindow.java:220)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is the part of code where line 25 is:

```
     public MainWindow() {
        initComponents();
        selectfolder.removeAllItems();
        String tempordir = ("src/easytext/textfiles/");
        String[] arr = new java.io.File(tempordir).list();
/*line 25 */         int len = arr.length;
        //System.out.println("arr.lenght è: "+arr.length);
        for (int i = 0; i<len; ++i){            
                selectfolder.addItem(arr[i]);}
          selecttext.removeAllItems();
        tempordir = ("src/easytext/textfiles/"+selectfolder.getSelectedItem().toString());
        arr = new java.io.File(tempordir).list();
        for (int i = 0; i<len; ++i){            
                selecttext.addItem(arr[i]);}
    GetText("src/easytext/textfiles/"+selectfolder.getSelectedItem().toString()+"/"+selecttext.getSelectedItem().toString());    
    }
```

So it looks like the nullpointerecxeption is thrown as i refer to the lenght of len array.

How can i solve this?
Thanks in advance, and sorry once again if i made some dumb mistake or didn't see something clear. I'm really spending some time on this without getting to a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`File.list()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29):

> An array of strings naming the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be empty if the directory is empty. **Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.**

So it sounds like the directory `src/easytext/textfiles/` probably doesn't exist from where you're executing the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the super quick answer. Tried to add the folder by right clicking on the project and adding it in the sources tab.
Also added a if (arr != null) block that includes the for cycle... but same story.

Comment: @Street: Your code is looking at what's in the *file system* - which isn't the same as what's in your jar file. If you compare the array with `null` you definitely *shouldn't* see the same error.

Comment: Thanks Jon. It took me a while, but using this:  String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir"); and creating the folders into c:\\ got finally the program work.
I will now figure out how to make it work in the same folder where i will copy the executable. It's a relief to see stuff working properly.
I know that you must be tired and bored by newbies question, but less synthetic and a bit of suggestions more would be totally great and time saving. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Street: You didn't give enough information to be able to suggest things, really. We didn't know whether you really *wanted* to look for a file in the file system, or whether you should be using a resource embedded within the jar file, fetched using `Class.getResourceAsStream` or something similar. Give more information in the question, and you're likely to get more detail in the response. (I'm not sure what you mean by "less synthetic", btw.)

Comment: My bad then. With less synthetic i meant the second answer, but since i wasn't clear, you're right. 
What i want to do is to use folders embedded in the jar file.
This program should read some subfolders from a folder and list them as categories in a combo box, and then in another combo box, list the txt files and show the preview on a textarea. I have to give it to people who cannot access the file system because is working on company machines, but need to access text files quickly without opening a word processor every time.
So they create folders and put txt files inside.